# How to put in a range for a variable

Tags: python-2.7

```
def getPoints(n):

    if n==1:
        return [1,11]
    elif n==(range(2,10)):
        return [n] 
    elif n==(range(10,13)):
        return [10]
```

For example, if `n==12` I want it to return `[10]`,and if `n==5` I want it return `[5]`. I am getting no return back from the Python shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider this expression you wrote: `n==(range(2,10))`

`n` presumably is a single number - it cannot possibly be equal to a range of numbers!

However, you could write the test as `n in range(2,10)` and it would do what you want - although somewhat inefficiently, as it would actually be creating a list of numbers each time the test is performed, then searching linearly through that list.  Using `xrange` instead of `range` would be more efficient, as it does not actually create the list.

Another way to do the same test would be `2 <= n < 10` (which is basically the same thing as `(2 <= n) and (n < 10)`)